# I keep getting compiling error expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘void’ void *runner(void *param)

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile this c program that uses threads to multiple matrices together. However I keep getting this error.

expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘void’
 void *runner(void *param)

Below is the code that it is referring to.

```
//The thread will begin control in this function
void *runner(void *param)
{
    struct v *data = param;
    int n, sum = 0;

    for(n = 0; n < X; n++)
    {
            sum += a[data->i][n] * b[n][data->j];
    }

    c[data->i][data->j] = sum;

    pthread_exit(0);
}


void *runner(void *param);
```

Comment: The error must be in the lines previous to that, perhaps you've forgotten to end a `struct` definition with a semicolon.

Comment: What is the last non-comment, non-blank line *before* `void *runner(...` ? If it is a `#include` directive, what is the last non-comment, non-blank post-processed text line in the included file? Related, there are *two* instances of the text `void *runner(void *param)` in the posted code, and you never mentioned which one is delivering the error you're getting. The latter is a prototype, and frankly belongs *before* the formal definition; not after. And, unrelated, your function that claims to return `void*` never does.

Comment: @Pablo I figured out what the problem was, I was missing a semi-colon in an unusual spot. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should declare the function before the implementation, or put it in a header file.